# How to insert marker into c code so that it appear in .elf file?

Tags: c, elf

I want to check if .elf file was built from specific code or from some other code

Is there any way to write something on C so that it can be identified by looking into binary elf file?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to do something like this? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and think about how this question could be one.

Comment: How about just having a checksum? Outside of the executable file, since it can easily be modified.

Comment: How can you prevent someone from copying this marker and putting it into their own code?

Comment: But if I modify my program then checksum will also change. I want to have some kind of constant that can be identified in .elf

Comment: Of course somebody can do this. It's not about protection

Comment: How about adding a variable: const int roy_rogers_marker =252525; There would be no run time penalty and you could see it with "nm"

Comment: Maybe you want to [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) you your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution that works for me:

```
static const char MARKER[] __attribute__((used)) = "A_A_A_A";
```

Answer (score 4):

Well I suppose you could just insert a literal string into your code. If you don't actually use this string, the compiler might decide to remove it during optimization, so perhaps you could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *id_string = "MARKER";
  if (argc < 0) {  // (never true)
    puts(id_string);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's right and we can use `string` command to check the marker string. Just a thought

Answer (score 2):

Why complicate things? The way to insert things into ELF binaries is through declaring global variables and non-static functions. No need to unreliably dig through the binary with strings and other tools like that or dig for magic numbers which could be accidentally generated by something.

```
int this_is_my_marker;
```

There will be a symbol called `this_is_my_marker` visible in the symbol table.

This assumes of course that you're on a relatively sane system with dynamic libraries and unixy semantics (which is almost implied by ELF). The reason why all global variables/functions end up in the symbol table by default is because it is legal for dynamic libraries to resolve symbols from the main program. Since this has been done for pretty much ever there's little risk that someone will invent a unixy operating system where this isn't done. (this is also why gcc has those weird `-fvisibility` flags)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `db` (or `.byte`) statement.

```
__asm {
    db 0x00 0x01 0x02
}
```

Do not forget to jump over this piece of code.